# Research y’a college

Tags: python

I’m practicing Python using IDLE at college and I have a problem concerning a program calculating a distance between two points in a cartesian plane. I wrote a `dist` function as:

```
def_dist(L1, L2):
    s=0
    n=len(L1)
    for k in range (n):
        s+=L1[k]-L2[k]
    return s**0,5
```

With L1 and L2 being two lists of data. The problem is about my interactive platform which doesn’t show me the results and lines to write my data's lists.

Is there a syntax mistake or is it another problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is not your interactive platform at all, but the fact that your code is invalid and won't run. Define your function without an underscore:

```
def dist(L1, L2):
```

If you want to see intermediate results in a calculation loop the normal approach is `print()`:

```
for k in range (n):
    s+=L1[k]-L2[k]
    print(s)
```